# excel functionality on html table

Tags: html, excel

I have a html table with ~500cells. Each cell has a input text. I need the functionality of excel which allow to complete cells by mouse drag and drop. Google docs also allow this functionality.

Do you have an idea about how can I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let the table be the wrapper and use a DIV inside each cell to hold the contents. Move the DIVs, not the table cells.

You probably want to look at jQuery UI draggables: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

If you've got the budget, go straight for ext.js: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-2

Comment: TY for your answer. I'll definitely use jQuery. I've take a look on google docs spreadsheet with firebug. They also use divs.

Comment: I use EXT.JS. It's the best $600 you could ever spend. It will save you weeks of work and you'll look like a star.